# How do I make the swipe in kivymd implement the content of a tab

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

The on_tab_switch function and event seems to work only when the tab is tapped so how do I make the swipe implement pagination the on_carousel_index and on_slide_progress seems not to be working at the moment. When a swipe to a tab is done the tab should do the same thing it does when it's tapped. How can one get that done in kivymd and kivy